# User control: For each object in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, user-controls

What I want to achieve is that with each and every object (user) that is existing in the database I want to create a user control and display it in the form.

```
 UserControl1 u = new UserControl1();
 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(u);
```

This is currently a user in my code: (NOTE: I'm using Entity Framework)

```
public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Review = new HashSet<Review>();
        }

        public string username { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Review> Review { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my method to get all users:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return db.User.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The problem is that I am out of ideas where to go next, I know that it's a bad situation to ask like this, but I really got no idea :(

Comment: Instead of manually adding controls to the form, why not nest the control in a repeater of some kind and just bind the collection of users to the repeater?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a for loop? How to pass an object to your controls?

Comment: Maybe I just need a time-out.. been working for long now thanks anyway

Comment: @btmach - Take a look at my answer and let me know if that is what you are asking. If not, it might help focus you onto the question?

Comment: I'll leave it for today, but defo check it out, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but will have a go at answering it. Depending on type (WinForms, WPF, ASP .NET) you could bind, but failing that you could hand crank like this:

```
var users = GetAllUsers();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    UserControl1 u = new UserControl1();
    u.UserName = user.username; 
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(u);
 }
```

Where you can then set up the user-control with information from the `user` in the loop. How you setup is another question, do you inject into constructor, expose properties etc. BUT - If this is NOT what you meant please could you clarify your question.